# Node js 'TypeError: app.route is not a function' -

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting the following error:

```
olddognewtrix123:~/workspace (master) $ node server.js
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/routes/index.js:7
        app.route('/')
            ^

TypeError: app.route is not a function
```

...and have no idea why.

I am building this in c9.io

Here is the updated github repo:

https://github.com/olddognewtrix123/nodeJSvignettes

Here is the code wherein I believe the error lies:

server,js:

```
 var express = require('express');

 var session = require('express-session');
 var path = require('path');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 var mongodb=require("mongodb")
 var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
 var routes = require('./app/routes/index.js');

 var app = express();

 app.use('/controllers', express.static(process.cwd() + '/app/controllers'));
 app.use('/public', express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));


 var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

 routes(app);

 app.listen(port,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
 });
```

index.js:

```
 'use strict';

 var path = process.cwd();

 module.exports = function (app){

    app.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(path + '/public/index.html');
        });

 };
```

Why am I getting this error????

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what version of node/express/etc. ? what is the value of `app` at the line in question?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "async": "~2.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.3",
    "socket.io": "~2.0.4"

Comment: and, I'm sorry, "the value of app"?

Comment: the version of node  is v6.11.2

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. Can you try assigning app from `express()` in your index.js and see if you get the same problem?

Comment: I am sorry - what do you mean " try assigning app from express()"? Sorry to be a dummy.

Comment: I mean before you do `app.route('/')`, which refers to the incoming app parameter, try doing `app = express()` similar to how you've done it in server.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two syntax you can try .
There is no app.route as you are passing.

index.js:

```
 'use strict';

 var path = process.cwd();

 module.exports = function (app){

    app.get('/',function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(path + '/public/index.html');
        });

 };
```

OR THIS

```
 'use strict';

 var path = process.cwd();
 var router = express.Router()
 module.exports = function (app){
   router.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.sendFile(path + '/public/index.html');
   })

 };
```